# JPA, nativeQuery The value is shown above

Tags: html, spring, postgresql, jpa, web

The code below is repository

```
 @Query
                (
                        value = "select min(id) as id, coalesce (sum(case when points > 0 then points end), 0) as points, userid" +
                                " from books" +
                                " where userid = ?1" +
                                " group by userid", nativeQuery = true
                )
        JamInfo findPlus(Long userid);

    @Query
            (
                    value = "select min(id) as id, coalesce(sum(case when points < 0 then points*-1 end),0)as points, userid" +
                            " from books" +
                            " where userid = ?1" +
                            " group by userid", nativeQuery = true
            )
    JamInfo findMinus(Long userid);
```

The code below is controller

```
JamInfo jamplus = jamInfoRepository.findPlus(id);
JamInfo jamminus = jamInfoRepository.findMinus(id);
model.addAttribute("jamplus", jamplus);
model.addAttribute("jamminus", jamminus);
```

If you print it like this, it will be unified with the value of jamplus written first. How can the two values ​​be output differently?

Comment: What does the output look like and how do you want it to look?

Comment: I want jamplus and jamminus to display different values.
If jamplus is on the top, jamminus is also displayed as jamplus. If jamminus is on the top, jamplus is the jamminus value.

Comment: Could you do something like `model.addAttribute("jamplus", jamplus.points);`?

Comment: The arguments to jamplus. are getPoint and setPoint. I tried but I get an error

Comment: JamInfo Table is
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long userid;

    private int points;

Comment: What's the error message when trying `model.addAttribute("jamplus", jamplus.getPoint());`?

Comment: I have replaced $ {jamplus} and $ {jamminus} in jsp to avoid the error, but the result is the same.